# Need a query about a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date field with entries 11/12,12/14 as here 11&12 are dates and 12 & 14 are years. I need them in a format of 11/2012,12/2014. How can i do that please reply me???

Comment: checkout mysql `date_format` and `str_to_date` functions.

Comment: `11&12` are months, perhaps?

Comment: I'm confused. Define `date field`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(substring(date_field, 1, 3), '20', substring(date_field, 4, 2))
from your_table
```

or

```
select insert(date_field,, 4, 0, '20')
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

DECLARE
   @insert_characters VARCHAR(2),
   @str VARCHAR(5)

SET @insert_characters = '20'
SET @str = '11/12'

SELECT LEFT(@str, 3) +@insert_characters + right(@str,2)